# Setting a browser window to remain visible when unfocused?

Tags: browser, window, visibility

Is it possible to have a browser window that remains visible even when unfocused? What I mean by this is something like when you minimize a Skype call, for example, a small window appears with your peer's camera and it remains visible no matter what you're doing on your desktop (unless viewing something in fullscreen, of course). Is this at all possible for a browser application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, I decided to check a less-than-optimal method for any options that allowed this kind of behavior. [MDN's page on `window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open) suggests an `alwaysRaised` flag that sounds exactly like what I want, but given the amount of extensions that block this method in many circumstances I don't know if this would be a viable solution for production code. It's the only thing I could find though.